# Set log level for built in keywords in robotframework

Tags: robotframework

In robot framework, it looks like it logs messages for keywords like "=" by default with 'INFO' log level. Ex:

```
<Test case>
  ${xyz} = "hello"
```

Would log message with:

```
'INFO': ${xyz} = "hello"
```

I would like to lower the log level for this to 'DEBUG' or 'TRACE' but can't seem to find it in the source code.
An advice for this?

Comment: Can you provide a rationale for wanting this? Have you tried a less detailed level like `robot -L WARN` for your log file generation?

Comment: Well, some of the variables set involves setting passwords or so.  I want to be able to suppress the message.  And many of them are very verbose.  I use a RobotListener to filter the messages further.  It's tricky to distinguish Builtin keyword and custom LOG INFO messages (unless I put in a specific pattern in the LOG INFO messages).

Answer (score 6):

Also, you can set your log level in the code. Like this:

```
  Test Setup                Set Log Level    TRACE
```

Then in the log.html file, a visible log level dropdown is shown in the upper right corner. This allows users to remove messages below the chosen level from the view. This can be useful especially when running tests at the TRACE level.

for more information see: http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#visible-log-level

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried to execute the test bringing the whole execution to a deeper level "DEBUG" or "TRACE" adding this `-L trace` or `-L debug` to your test call. `robot -L trace mytest.robot` for instance.

Comment: If I have another step (like LOG "..." INFO), that content will be hidden as well.  I want to control the log level of keyword individually.

Answer (score 0):

Source code defined like this

```
    def log(self, message, level='INFO', html=False, console=False,
            repr=False, formatter='str'):
        u"""Logs the given message with the given level.

        Valid levels are TRACE, DEBUG, INFO (default), HTML, WARN, and ERROR.
        Messages below the current active log level are ignored. See
        `Set Log Level` keyword and ``--loglevel`` command line option
        for more details about setting the level.
```

usage example
Log  you message:{message}  level=DEBUG